# Realm - mix models from different projects

Tags: java, android, orm, module, realm

I have a model in my Main project:

```
public class A extends RealmObject{

    private String var1;
    private B var2;

    //... more
}
```

Also, I have my class `B` in my library (different android-studio module)

```
public class B extends RealmObject{

    private String var1;

    //... more
}
```

I cannot build this because of:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex: Cause:
>   com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
>   Lio/realm/DefaultRealmModule;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':Container:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

I'm setting my own module:

```
@NonNull
public static RealmConfiguration getRealmConfiguration(String name) {
    return new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(name)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .modules(new MyRealmModule())
            .build();
}

@RealmModule(allClasses = true, library = true)
public static class MyRealmModule{
}
```

It should take my models from both projects, Am I right?

my gradle:

> classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:2.0.2"

and

> apply plugin: 'realm-android'

in both projects

How to do it in right way?

Comment: You're supposed to have a module per project. Library projects must expose their objects via a schema

Answer (score 3):

Your library project must expose a `@RealmModule` that exposes `library = true, allClasses = false` and only object `B`. And you should add that module to the configuration for the project that has A.

And you can choose to either add `Realm.getDefaultModule()` in your project, or also create a module for the project itself as `library = false, allClasses = true`.

```
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class LibraryModule { // in library 
}
```

and

```
.modules(new LibraryModule(), Realm.getDefaultModule()) // in project
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use RealmModule to expose your schema in library project.

Check out the doc: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#sharing-schemas